# Are importing nodes not added as async to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html-imports

I remember reading somewhere that if a `script` tag is added to `DOM` using `appendChild` it's not blocking and behaves as if it had `async` attribute. Today I was reading [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) and it has the following code snippet:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'import';
link.href = 'file.html';
//link.setAttribute('async', ''); // make it async!
```

So I'm wondering isn't the behavior described for `script` tag the same for `link` tag? Why add `async` attribute manually?

Comment: First of all, the behavior of the `rel="import"` is still a Working Draft, and the one that author was linking to was the Editor's Draft. That means all of this could change tomorrow. So there's little reason to think that the behaviors won't coalesce. Of course, there's also little reason to think that they will... Secondly, as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility), different browsers/versions handle script-inserted `script` elements differently.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thanks for your comment. Regarding `script` tag, as I understand all modern browsers default `async` to `true` for script injected scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined [in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#interface-import), every `<link rel="import>` tag not marked as `async` is blocking the parser.

If you add the `<link>` with `appendChild()`, it doesn't block the current script execution but in fact it will block the parsing until the imported document is loaded.

If after that you add another tag -with `appendChild()`- who is referenced by the imported document, you still need to specify the `async` attribute.

```
document.head.appendChild( link )
//link should be async if it uses the element below:
document.body.appendChild( element )
```